# How do you force a ShellFolder to call CreateViewObject again and request a new ShellView

Tags: c++, windows, windows-shell, shell-extensions

I have a Namespace extension with a Custom Shell View implementation.

I'm trying to use IExplorerPaneVisibility.GetPaneState method but I'm not receiving any requests the first time the folder is loaded. This is because Windows gets this information from the DefView when the namespace is loaded initially. I realized that subsequent navigation in the namespace would prompt GetPaneState requests to my Custom Shell View.
source:

But since I have only one Shell Folder in the namespace, I have to simulate navigation to itself by clicking on the folder name in the explorer address bar. This prompts a ShellFolder.CreateViewObject call with IID_IShellView.

Is there anyway I can force a ShellFolder.CreateViewObject call with IID_IShellView programmatically?